# Copy and paste between forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to copy a form field and associated content from one form to another?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

This is not a feature of Cognito Forms. While you can make a copy of a complete form. We do not offer the ability to copy a single field out of one form, and into another form.